# How can I make DashPathEffect or PathDashPathEffect space dashes consistently

Tags: java, android

You can see in the image that these two dashed lines do not coincide. They are drawn along the same path, starting from the same place with the same DashPathEffect. The only difference is the sweepAngle. I've also tried PathDashPathEffect using a circle as the shape but the result is the same.

I want the dots drawn exactly on top of each other. I can't delete the path underneath, because then at the start of the yellow line, the dots will not align. Is this a bug?

[image: Dots not aligned]

Comment: so you want something like [this](http://pasteboard.co/98qRKFHDm.png)? or somethong else?

Comment: Exactly like that! How did you do it?

Comment: with `PathDashPathEffect` only

Comment: Did you calculate the start of the second arc manually? As in, count the number of dots and spacing so you know where the next arc will start to keep the spacing consistent?

Comment: yes, sure thing

Comment: Can you show me some code? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: float toDegrees(float dotNumber) {
            return dotNumber * 360 / 40;
        }

Comment: I don't understand how you can get the dot number. PathDashPathEffect only takes an arbitrary spacing parameter and doesn't tell me how many dots have been drawn in the first arc.

Comment: so calculate `advance` so it is: 2 * radius * PI / totalNumberOfDots

Comment: So `advance` is in pixels? It would be nice if the docs specified this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/u7L4V5gd)

Comment: Excellent it worked. DashPathEffect still doesn't work with this technique. I had to use PathDashPathEffect like you said. I guess its a little bug.